# barplot plot extra bars

Tags: line, bar-chart, markers

I am fairly new to R, so I hope you can help me out with a simple solution. In a barplot in R, I want to add horizontal lines on top of the bars that represent the different categories on the x-axis (which represent expected values). The expected values vary per category. Here's a little piece of my script.

```
nem=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6)
fish=c(103,72,44,13,3,1,1)
table=data.frame(nem,fish)
ticks=seq(1,6,1)
graph=barplot(fish,las=2,ylim=c(0,120),main="Number of nematodes per fish")
axis(1,at=graph,labels=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6))
```

Hope you can help me out!

[Image of barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDB2E.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope that can help you - just put the lines under your code.

```
linelength <- c(10,20,12,50,12,14,21)

xl <- seq(from=0.7, by=1.2, along.with = fish) 
yl <- cbind(fish, fish + linelength)

for(z in 1:length(fish)){
  lines(x=rep(xl[z], 2), y=yl[z,])
}
```

Comment: nice. I also answer this question because i have to little reputation points to help you with your other [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39817711/reshape-dataframe-from-long-to-wide.). I need there some values of the `data.frame`  to help you, like you did in this question with the object `fish`.